# Find Specific Value (Zeros) in .csv Files

Tags: search, design-patterns, grep, matching

I'm using the following to error-check directories below the current location to find files with a "0" value on a single line.  The grep string I'm using finds all the zeros but I need to find any files with a single "0" on a line in files ending with SPD-daily.csv.
I'm using this -

```
grep -R --include "*SPD-daily.csv" 0 ./
```

and I get just about everything with a 0 in it.  Thanks,

Comment: The pattern to find a single zero on a line is `^0$`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you want to find any files that contain *any* line with just a zero, or any files that contain *only* a single line with zero. For the former case:

```
grep -Rx --include "*SPD-daily.csv" 0 .
```

The -x tells grep to find an exact match, so lines with a zero *and* other chars will be ignored.

For the latter case, where the file must contain only one line containing zero:

```
grep -Rxn --include "*SPD-daily.csv" 0 . | grep ':1'
```

The -n tells grep to print the line number. This output is piped to grep again which looks for the "line 1" bit.